# How to do this complex intergral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How would you evaluate $$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}dz$$

would you just need to plug in for the residues

as the roots are at $$\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

and then multiply by $2\pi i$ or is it more complicated then that?

Comment: No, I do not think it is any more complicated then that.  Why would it be?

Comment: additionally you have to determine which of the roots is inside the unit circle

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: Since both poles of the integrand lie inside the circle $|z| = 2$, the integrand is analytic outside. You can deform the contour to a large circle of radius $R$ without changing its value. Since the integrand falls off as $R^{-2}$ for large $R$, the integral vanishes as $R \to \infty$. This implies the original contour integral also vanishes. There is no need to compute any residue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1.$ If $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ and $|z_0|<2$, then we have

$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z-z_0}dz=2 \pi i$$

(winding number !).

$2.$ Let $z_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Then find $A,B \in \mathbb C$ such that

$$\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}=\frac{A}{z-z_1}+\frac{B}{z-z_2}.$$

Since $|z_{1,2}|=1<2$ we get from $1$. that

$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}dz=2 \pi i (A+B).$$